# How to make a certain part of textarea read-only

Tags: javascript, html

I have a text area and I dynamically add data to it and it works fine. What I wanted to achieve was after the data is appended that data cant be altered (edited) but after the last element of the data user can start typing on the textarea. I was thinking of maybe calculating the length of string data the set read-only to that part. How can I achieve this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**For a visual example take a look at the terminal of this website**: https://www.online-python.com/

```js
function test() {
  x = 'this is a string to be appended to text area'
  document.getElementById("textArea").value = x;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textArea"></textarea>
<button onclick="test()">Append</button>
```

Comment: You probably can't do that. A better strategy might be to move the earlier text to a paragraph above.

Comment: OT but maybe if you explain what is the actual result you want to achieve and not a demo, there might be better ways to achieve it (instead of freezing some text in a textarea)

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia what I wrote is exactly what I need

Comment: @seriously how is [that link](https://www.online-python.com/) showing anything close to your question?

Comment: did you read the description to the link @Olian04

Comment: @seriously glhf -_-

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `keydown` event listener that checks whether the `selectionStart` is smaller than the length of the textarea's value minus the length of the string appended:

```js
let x = 'this is a string to be appended to text area'
var hasAppended = false;

function test() {
  hasAppended = true
  document.getElementById("textArea").value = x;
}

textArea.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (hasAppended) {
    if (this.selectionStart > this.value.length - x.length && this.selectionStart != this.value.length) {
      e.preventDefault()
      e.stopPropagation()
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<textarea id="textArea"></textarea><button onclick="test()">Append</button>
```

Comment: but user cant add text after the string

Comment: @seriously I've updated my answer.

Comment: still don't work the string data can be edited

Comment: @seriously The string data cannot be edited for me.

Comment: thats weird, just checked it again It gets edited

Comment: oh figured it out the problem is when you resize the text area

Comment: Hey if you are still online I was writing the terminal code and would like your input. please take a look at this fiddle (it's a collab live fiddle) press on append: jsfiddle.net/vq4bwsdz/261/#&togetherjs=LyaQcADj0x

Comment: The current issue I have in the jsfiddle code is when you press append over 1 time the input box's height gets multiplied every call (the height should have been the same every call (only offset position should have only changed). I couldn't figure out the issue but I think it is because I used offset.top() on a dynamically loaded element.

Comment: The Fiddle link is updated check this one: jsfiddle.net/seriously_/03t1nucL/#&togetherjs=LyaQcADj0x

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to selectively mark parts of a `<textarea>` read-only, however, a similar effect can be achieved with `contenteditable` elements:

```js
function test() {
  const x = 'this is a string to be appended to text area'
  const span = document.createElement('span')
  span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(x))
  span.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'false')
  document.getElementById("textArea").appendChild(span);
}
```

```css
#textArea{
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="textArea" contenteditable="true"></div>
<button onclick="test()">Append</button>
```

However, this will still allow the user to delete the read-only block, or write *before* it.

Comment: this isn't a possible solution I subject you edit or delete your answer to avoid downvote by other people

Answer (score 0):

This almost works.

EDIT:
Improved it a bit by changing `keydown` to `keyup`.

Now there is no need for space at the end of the read-only text and CTRL+a and then backspace will make the text come back almost instantly.

Maybe you can improve on it.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('textArea').addEventListener('keyup', function (e){
    var readOnlyLength = parseInt(document.getElementById("textArea").getAttribute('data-readOnlyLength') );
    var currentLength = parseInt(document.getElementById("textArea").value.length );
    if (readOnlyLength >= currentLength ) {
        document.getElementById("textArea").value = document.getElementById("textArea").getAttribute('data-readonly') ;
    }
  }, false);
};

function test() {
  x = 'this is a string to be appended to text area'
  document.getElementById("textArea").value = x;
  document.getElementById("textArea").setAttribute('data-readonly' , x); 
  document.getElementById("textArea").setAttribute('data-readOnlyLength' , x.length); 
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textArea"></textarea>
<button onclick="test()">Append</button>
```

Comment: is there any way to make new line when the string ends then read only everything before?

Comment: I just tried to change keydown to keyup - and now the space ad the end is not needed, also CTRL+a and backspace will make the read-only come back instantly

Comment: Can you elaborate your comment? Just to make sure I understand what you are asking

Comment: so if you go to the link I provided above and scroll down to the terminal I basically need that functionality

Comment: Hmm maybe - but I think it will be pretty hard. Is there a specific reason why you want to force this functionality into a Textarea ? I think it would be a lot easier using almost anything else

Comment: really like what else. Note I will also display code information on it so space is needed.

Comment: Like in your link, it uses divs and even input fields. Or many of the libs that emulate terminals could also get you going quickly - like https://www.cssscript.com/terminal-emulator/

Comment: I'm already using skulpt a dedicated library for running python compiled in js. I just need the best possible way to display it and also get command back from the user

Comment: Plus using a third party based ide and sending client code to someone elses server is a NO NO

Comment: I see. In my mind a textarea is not the best way to display it. I would use a div to display the data and then an input field below for the user to respond/send back info.

Comment: yeah was thinking about the same thing too. I will  code it and post an update above

Comment: Hey if you are still online I was writing the code and would like your input. please take a look at this fiddle (it's a collab live fiddle): https://jsfiddle.net/vq4bwsdz/261/#&togetherjs=LyaQcADj0x

Comment: The current issue I have in the jsfiddle code is when you press append over 1 time the input box's height gets multiplied every call (the height should have been the same every call (only offset position should have only changed). I couldn't figure out the issue but I think it is because I used offset.top() on a dynamically loaded element.

Comment: The Fiddle link is updated check this one: https://jsfiddle.net/seriously_/03t1nucL/#&togetherjs=LyaQcADj0x